# TypeError: 'SwitchTo' object is not callable

Tags: python, selenium

I'm here to ask a question.
I'm trying to close a pop-up window.
This is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver.switch_to(driver.window_handles\[1\])
driver.close()
driver.switch_to(driver.window_handles\[0\])
```

But i could get only this.

```
TypeError: 'SwitchTo' object is not callable
```

How can i
please help me and Thx for reading this.

Comment: Read the docs, switch_to is not a method: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call the `switch_to()` method on the driver object directly.
You should first get the driver object from `webdriver.Chrome()`.

Below is the solution.

```python
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
driver.close()
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
```